# mysql_install_db: How to set the root password

Tags: mysql

mysql 5.6 seems to have a new --random-passwords option for mysql_install_db, which lets me discover the root password:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-install-db.html#option_mysql_install_db_random-passwords

But what can I do with mysql 5.5? The documentation suggests that the root password should be empty, but I cannot seem to connect with no password (or an empty password), so i cannot set a real root password:

For instance:

I initialize the database like so:

```
$ mysql_install_db --no-defaults --user=murrayc --datadir=/tmp/testmysql/data
```

I start the server like so:

```
$ mysqld_safe --no-defaults --user=murrayc --port=3308 --datadir='/tmp/testmysql/data' --socket='/tmp/testmysql/mysqld.sock' --pid-file='/tmp/testmysql/pid'
```

But when I try to set the root password like so (I believe that --user in this case refers to the mysql user, not the linux user):

```
$ mysqladmin --no-defaults --port=3308 --user=root --password='' password 'somenewpassword'
```

I get this error:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upon installation, `root@localhost` does not have a password.

You should be able to connect without a password by just doing this:

```
$ mysql -uroot
```

Try the following:

```
$ mysqladmin --no-defaults --port=3308 --user=root password 'somenewpassword'
```

or you can do it the stubborn way:

```
$ service mysql restart --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
$ mysql -e"UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password('somenewpassword') WHERE user='root'"
$ service mysql restart
$ mysql -uroot -p
```

## UPDATE 2013-01-02 16:47 EDT

I am sorry, I overlooked the port number.

Here is the problem: you cannot use root@localhost against a non-3306 port unless you use the TCP/IP protocol. Please try this:

```
$ mysqladmin --no-defaults --port=3308 --user=root --protocol=tcp password 'somenewpassword'
```

Comment: No, that's the point. Login is not possible with no password:
`10:41:12 ~$ mysql -uroot --port=3311
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Commands such as "service mysql restart" are for the system's regular mysql process. I am initializing a separate database and starting a separate mysqld instance.

Comment: Many thanks for the update. I might never have figures out that it needed the --protocol option.

Answer (score -2):

Try to run `mkdir -p var tmp` before `mysql_install_db`.

create mysql db failed in my situation.

If var and tmp are Not created previously and use them as the paras of mysql_install_db,
we can start mysqld successfully.
try to use mysql or mysqladmin connect to server, I got the err:
access denied for 'root'@'localhost'

Maybe the question's cause is the same with mine.

Comment: Try to run that from where/in what directory? What error is that supposed to solve?

Comment: basedir of mysql.

Comment: Please [edit] that into your answer. Also I'm not sure I understand your second sentence. Could you clarify? Thanks.